# How to set max wait time for http response in Android Cronet?

Tags: android, kotlin, http, connection-timeout, cronet

I use Android's recommended Cronet library for making HTTP requests, however, I couldn't find information on how to implement certain features. For example, I need to set max wait time for all HTTP requests. In other words, if the HTTP request takes more than 'X' seconds - it should be considered as a FAILED request. How can I configure this in Cronet?

My code:

```
fun initCronet() { // this is called only once
    executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    engine = CronetEngine.Builder(context) 
        .enableHttp2(true)
        .build()
}

suspend fun myFunction() {
    suspendCoroutine<HttpResponseContainer> {
        val callback = CoroutinesNetworkCallback(it)
        val url = "http://myhost.com/my-endpoint"

        engine.newUrlRequestBuilder(url, callback, executor)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
            .build().start()
    }
}
```

Callback looks approximately like this:

```
class CoroutinesNetworkCallback (
  private val continuation: Continuation<HttpResponseContainer>,
) : UrlRequest.Callback() {

  override fun onRedirectReceived(request: UrlRequest, info: UrlResponseInfo, newUrl: String) {
      request.cancel()
  }

  override fun onResponseStarted(request: UrlRequest, info: UrlResponseInfo) {
      // init buffer
  }

  override fun onReadCompleted(request: UrlRequest, info: UrlResponseInfo, buffer: ByteBuffer) {
      // retrieve response
  }

  override fun onFailed(request: UrlRequest, info: UrlResponseInfo, error: CronetException) {
      continuation.resumeWithException(RuntimeException("request failed"))
  }

  override fun onSucceeded(request: UrlRequest, info: UrlResponseInfo) {
      continuation.resume(HttpResponseContainer(httpStatusCode))
  }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, as per this https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/components/cronet/android/java/src/org/chromium/net/urlconnection/CronetHttpURLConnection.java#444. Seems like they don't support timeout per request, probably just add a timer for overall request

Answer (score -2):

you can add  connectTimeout , writeTimeout  and readTimeout with builder

connectTimeout  : max time to try connect with host address
writeTimeout   and readTimeout : max time to  send request and receive response

Comment: CronetEngine and newUrlRequest builders don't have such properties. Code example would be much appreciated